# Не работает margin в HTML + CSS

Tags: html, css, margin, отступы

Почему появляются отступы, хотя я убираю их в коде. Пробовал многое, но безуспешно.

Код HTML:

```
<html lang="ru">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>EmilAhmaServer – Главная</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="header" align="center">
      <img id="banner" src="image/banner.png" width="100%">
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Код CSS:

```
* {
  padding: 0
  margin: 0;
}

#header {
  width: 100%;
}
```

[image: Отступы]

Comment: `* {  padding: 0;  margin: 0; }` запятую пропустили

Comment: @eccs0103 точку с запятой*

Comment: @ΝNL993 да, типа того. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Банально точку с запятой забыл :) (@eccs0103)